# Clicking on a Windows 7 icon only opens command prompt, not the target

Tags: windows-7

Clicking on a Windows-7 icon only opens command prompt, not the target. 
It's the same problem with all installed programs.
It used to work, but got broken at some point.

Below is an example. Target is a .bat script that launches the application. That's the default installation.

As a workaround, I right-click on the icon, then copy-paste the path in "Target" field to command prompt, and then run it.

[image]

Comment: Did you try a System Restore back to a point before it stopped working?

Comment: Well, it started happening a while ago, but I found some time to "deal" with this only now. So I don't want to restore the system way back since it can mess up other things.